# MYSQL find field value that where never recorder previously

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization

Hi I have a table that logs user events.

```
date       | event | userId
2016/09/29 | A     | 10
2016/09/29 | A     | 3
2016/09/29 | A     | 2
2016/09/28 | A     | 2
2016/09/28 | B     | 2
2016/09/27 | A     | 1
2016/09/27 | A     | 1
2016/09/27 | B     | 1
```

I need to count for each day of the current month, the number of userId that were never seen before (to simplify, the number of new users).

I have come up with the following query for the current day.

```
SELECT DATE(date) AS time, COUNT(DISTINCT userId) AS count FROM event 
WHERE DATE(date) = date(now()) 
AND userId NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT userId FROM event WHERE DATE(date) <= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    AND userId IS NOT NULL
)
```

But I am not able to find an efficient query to get the same result for each day of the current month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT myDate, COUNT(userId) AS user_count
FROM (
    SELECT userId, DATE(MIN(date)) AS myDate
    FROM event 
    GROUP BY userId
) AS ch
GROUP BY myDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select fd date, count(1) newUserCount from 
(select min(date) fd ,userId from event where date between {monthStart} and {monthEnd}
group by userId )t group by fd
```

Find each user's first visit date of the month,and the daily count of new user of this month is each day's user count.

Hope this can help